# What's the purpose of these assembly register modifiers?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm looking at some C code with inline x86_64 assembly.

In the C-code, I see a couple of global declarations, with an assembly macro

```
static char *mem = NULL; // Gets malloc()'d before macro is called
static size_t phys = 0;

#define ASM_READ \
  asm volatile("xorq %%rax, %%rax\n",
               "1:\n"
               "movb (%%rcx), %%al\n"
               "shl $12, %%rax\n"
               "jz 1b\n"
               "movq (%%rbx, %%rax, 1), %%rbx\n"
               :
               : "c"(phys), "b"(mem)
               : "rax");
```

This is then later called in the code as ASM_READ.

My question is: how is it that rbx is getting loaded with the address of mem and rcx is loaded with the address of phys?

The "Intel IA-64" machine constraints in the gcc compiler docs (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) list "b" as a branch regsiter and "c" as a conditional register. Still, I don't see how this is forcing the mem and phys into rbx and rcx, respectively

Comment: IA-64 is Itanium, not x86_64. In the linked gcc documentation, the x86 section covers both x86_32 (a.k.a. IA-32 a.k.a. i386) and x86_64 (a.k.a. amd64)

Comment: Whoops! That was the entirety of the mistake. x86 family specifies those modifiers go to those registers. Thanks!

Comment: That's badly-written asm.  It clobbers `%rbx` without telling the compiler about it.  (Of course, when used for the Meltdown vulnerability, the architectural state after this statement doesn't matter, because the `movb` faults).  However, the whole loop to retry on zero is probably not needed; AFAICT it's based on a misunderstanding by the authors of the Meltdown paper from looking at Linux core-dumps where `rax` is always zero.  (Of course it is, because the `movb` faults so it still has its xor-zero value).  Also, `movzbl (%%rcx), %eax` would do the same thing without needing xor-zeroing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes! Finally! That retry-on-zero always bugged me when reading the Metldown paper but I've always been too afraid to dispute it.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I mentioned that in an email to the authors of the Meltdown authors (along with some other stuff).  I heard back from Werner Haas who said my analysis sounded right; so I guess they had been confused by the crash-dump register value, and thought it was always zero because something was forcing it to zero, rather than it was still zero because exceptions are taken *before* the faulting instruction completes (architecturally).  Hopefully when they have time to revise their rushed paper, they'll remove the loop and simplify to `movzx` instead of merging with the old `rax`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: But until then, see [my (untested) Meltdown sequence of instructions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177100/why-are-amd-processors-not-less-vulnerable-to-meltdown-and-spectre/177101#177101) which should work just as well (and includes a chain of 30x `sqrtpd` to delay retirement of the faulting load).  I hope the paper authors will copy it verbatim for an update to their paper.  (And Max: I'd suggest porting that sequence to GNU C inline asm).